# Nginx Reverse Proxy: Special Settings for one Path on Upstream Server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Nginx is used as reverse proxy in front of a Node server. The Node server has one path (`/ws`) where WebSockets are used, this path needs special settings.  `/ws` is not a directory, therefore a request to it must not have a trailing slash. What's the correct way to do configure this? The following configuration does not work, but shows what is intended.

```
location /service/ {
  proxy_read_timeout  30s;
  proxy_pass        http://service:8080/;

  # not working, requests are sent to http://service:8080/service/ws
  # instead http://service:8080/ws
  location /service/ws {  
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using a nested location, and I am not sure how `proxy_pass` is inherited by the inner block. You could try two independent `location` blocks with an explicit `proxy_pass` in each block:

```
location /service/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  30s;
    proxy_pass        http://service:8080/;
}
location /service/ws {  
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout  36000s;

    proxy_pass        http://service:8080/ws;
}
```